# Problem with publishing feed with mp3 attachment

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey all, i have an app that works both in canvas and tab.

my problem is that on the tab the feed with the attachment works great but on the canvas the attachment wont show up..

any ideas on how can i fix it? or if its a known bug in the Javascript SDK?

this is my javascript code:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  display: 'iframe',
  attachment : {
    media : [{
      type : 'mp3',
      src : 'http://midias.toingboo.pmovil.com.br/cont_din/fixo/blaving_audio/encNgjLDO73WjIzxRHk43yIxbycPKcU-xLt/2515.mp3',
      title : 'title',
      artist : 'artist',
      album : 'Blaving.com'
    }]
  }
});
```

of course i first do a FB.login()...

Answer (score 1):

To set the artist in the "new method", the mp3 should have the artist info in the id3 info

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the 'source' attribute, apparently facebook no longer uses the attachment object with media inside.

the correct way to do this is as follow:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  display: 'iframe',
  source: 'http://midias.toingboo.pmovil.com.br/cont_din/fixo/blaving_audio/encNgjLDO73WjIzxRHk43yIxbycPKcU-xLt/2515.mp3',
  name: 'title',
  description: 'description'
});
```